# AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'url'

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I'm writing some API tests in pytest which take in a `user` object which is generated from a utility class. Then it calls the `requests` library to make the required API calls.

Below is my code that tests the `/user` operations.

```
import requests

class users:
    def __init__(self, user_with_token):
        self.token = user_with_token["Token"]
        self.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Users/'
        self.headers = {'token': self.token}

    def get_all_users(self):
        return requests.get(self.url, headers=self.headers).status_code

    def delete_user(self):
        return requests.delete(self.url, headers=self.headers).text

    def update_user(self):
        return requests.post(self.url, headers=self.headers).text
```

Here are the tests that call the above:

```
import pytest
from endpoints.users import users

def get_all_users(user_with_token):
    result = users.get_all_users(user_with_token)
    assert result == 200

def test_delete_all_users(user_with_token):
    result = users.delete_user(user_with_token)
    assert "Current user deleted" in result
```

Here is the definition that generates fake data for the test to consume:

```
def generate_user_with_token():
    fake = Faker()
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/Register/'

    username = fake.name().split(' ', 1)[0],
    email = fake.email(),
    password = fake.random_int(min=0, max=9999)
    token = requests.post(url, json={'Username': username,'Email Address': email,'Password': password}).text.split()[-2]

    user = {
        "Username": username,
        "Email Address": email,
        "Password": password,
        "Token": token
    }

    return user
```

When I run it, however. I am receiving an error stating:

```
    def delete_user(self):
>       return requests.delete(self.url, headers=self.headers).text
E       AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'url'
```

Am I unable to use `self.url`? I wanted to not have to redeclare it in each defination as the endpoint is the same for each test.

Comment: How are you using the `users` class? What's the full error message?

Comment: Post has been edited.

Comment: You need to create a users instance, you're passing a dict and you're using the class method wrong. `users(user_with_token).delete_user()`. I'd consider refactoring the code though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `delete_user` function on the entire class, rather than a specific instance of the class. Also it is more common to make class names uppercase, so the class name would be `Users` rather than `user`. To create an instance of the `Users` class, you would do `users = Users(user_with_token)`.

When you call the `delete_user` function on the class (rather than an instance of the class) using `users.delete_user(user_with_token)`, the `user_with_token` dict is being passed as the `self` parameter to the method, which is where the error is coming from. When you instead call the function on a specific instance, Python will automatically make the `self` parameter be the instance.

When you use the class you should do something like the following (this code is assuming you have renamed your class from `users` to `Users` btw:

```
from endpoints.users import users

def get_all_users(user_with_token):
    users = Users(user_with_token)
    result = users.get_all_users()
    assert result == 200

def test_delete_all_users(user_with_token):
    users = Users(user_with_token)
    result = users.delete_user()
    assert "Current user deleted" in result
```

Notice that instead of `users.delete_user(user_with_token)`, the method is simply called with `users.delete_user()`, as your `delete_user` method is only expecting a single parameter - `self`, not two (`self`, and `user_with_token`). Once you have created an instance of the `Users` class, it will include the data from `user_with_token` so there is no need to also pass that data to the `delete_user` and `get_all_users` functions.